# "grep -Ff " doesn't highlighted pattern with colour in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, scripting

while running below command in terminal it's working fine with highlighted red and white colour matching with the pattern as per image below,

`$ grep -Ff file1.txt file2.txt`

Output: [image: expected output]

But when I put the same command in script as `pl.sh` file and run it it's not highlighting at all as above image. I am not sure what I am doing wrong! Do I need to change the script?

```
#!/bin/bash

# Main file:
echo -n "Choose the Main Assignment File : "
read mainfile

# Compare a file
echo -n "Choose a file to compare with : "
read comparefile

# Compare two files and highlight differences 
sudo grep -Ff "$mainfile" "$comparefile"
```

Comment: Your interactive shell likely has an *alias* that re-defines `grep` to use color ex. `alias grep='grep --color=auto'`

Comment: The command in the script is prefixed with `sudo`. Why?

Comment: @steeldriver Sorry I am novice in Linux env, so where I need to put that alias? In the same `pl.sh` file or somewhere else

Comment: Well bash scripts don't expand aliases by default - and neither does `sudo`. So you'd need to add the color option to grep explicitly ex. `grep --color=always -Ff "$mainfile" "$comparefile"`

Comment: @steeldriver - thanks, it's working. Great learning today.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your interactive shell likely has an alias that re-defines grep to use color when outputing to a terminal device ex. alias `grep='grep --color=auto'` (perhaps defined in the default `~/.bashrc` file).

Bash non-interactive scripts don't expand aliases by default - and neither does sudo. So you'd need to add the color option to grep explicitly ex.

```
grep --color=auto -Ff "$mainfile" -- "$comparefile"
```